# заметка будет помещена / размещена

Tags: приставка

Из текста, составленного иностранцем на сайте изучения языков lang-8:

> Сегодня я встал в 6 часов утра. Сейчас я составляю заметку об одном книжном магазине в Казахстане. Как написано в прежнем дневнике, эта заметка будет **помещена** в одном японском журнале.

Интересно, можно ли написать "размещена". Я нашел в "Словаре трудностей русского языка" ([стр. 454](https://books.google.ru/books?id=UVllAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA453&vq=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&hl=ru&pg=PA454#v=onepage&q&f=false)) описание различий между этими словами. Судя по этому описанию, выходит, что "размещена" - неверный вариант.

> Глагол "разместить" в соответствии с значением приставки *раз-* употребляется по отношению ко многим предметам, лицам или применительно к такому предмету, который представляет собой сложное целое, состоящее из многих (отделяемых) частей.
>   ...Неправильны поэтому: "И размещена (следует: помещена) глава в книге символично".

Но мне кажется, что "разместить" все-таки используется в этом значении (разместить заметку, статью и т.п.) в современном русском языке.

Мне "разместить" не резало слух, пока этот человек, изучающий русский язык, не спросил о разнице между данными словами. Дело в том, что я переправил его "помещена" на "размещена". Выходит, испортил правильный вариант. (0:

Мне интересно - как вы это воспринимаете. Может быть, в современном русском языке значения *помещена-размещена* уже "слились"? Вы бы исправили "размещена" при вычитке на "помещена"? Или не заметили бы разницы?

Comment: P.S. @АртёмЛуговой - а где в правилах сайта запрещены смайлики? (0:

Comment: Простите пожалуйста! По логике и казалось, что это смайлик, но я в жисть такого не видел, решил, что он каким-то неправильным получился. Даже загуглил такой, но ничего такого не нашёл. В любом случае это Ваше права даже придумывать смайлики, так что простите ещё раз!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - ничего страшного, просто стало интересно. (0: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: А что он выражает, этот смайлик?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - обычную улыбку. С большим носом. (0:

Comment: Пользуясь случаем, хочу спросить. Увидел, что у Вас данные профиля на других сайтах сообщества отличаются: тут по-русски, а там по-английски. Как так сделать? Я раньше думал, что это невозможно!

Comment: Понятно))))))))

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - нужно выбрать "save changes just for this community" (при правке профиля, в самом низу оранжевая кнопка слева)

Comment: Получилось, спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - you're welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Глаголы "поместить и разместить" **имеют разные оттенки значений**, но не обязательно при этом речь должна идти о многих предметах или сложных предметах.

Поместить - положить предмет в определенное место **(общее значение),** разместить - это также поместить предмет, но **с дополнительным значением "найти/подобрать для него место".**

Вариант 1. "Эта заметка будет помещена в одном японском журнале". Здесь не чувствуется дополнительного значения "подобрать место", поэтому желательно использовать глагол "поместить".

Вариант 2.  "Всякий желающий волен разместить информацию в Интернете без каких-либо, даже символических, затрат на публикацию". Здесь возможны оба варианта поместить/разместить, разместить информацию - это найти для нее место среди множества других публикаций.

Также: "Ведь в блоге можно разместить фото- и видеорепортаж, поделиться своими размышлениями".

Из словаря:

ПОМЕСТИТЬ, 1. что. Определить, расположить где-л., дать место для чего-л. П. книги на полку.  П. экспонат в центре зала.

РАЗМЕСТИТЬ, св. кого-что. 1. Расставить или разложить по местам, в определённом порядке; расположить.Р. мебель в комнате. Р. товары по полкам.

Answer (score 1):

> Дело в том, что я переправил его "помещена" на "размещена". Выходит,
>   испортил правильный вариант.

Да, это было не самое правильное решение. Автору лучше не пе6речить.)) 
Но, вопреки словарю (вернее - одгобокому его пониманию), "разместить" здесь вполне уместно, если это не сугубо официальный стиль речи. "Разместить заметку" - вполне уместный оборот, если не ограничиваться единственным, узко понимаемом, значением глагола. "Разместитить" здесь (поверьте дипломированному полиграфисту) идет от представления о верстке, заметку **размещают** на печатной странице издания или на экране. А это работа с макетом издания, не просто помещение чего-то куда-то. Заметка-то одна, но в ней много строк, которые надо *разместить* среди других подобных материалов. Так что, если есть желание подчеркнуть, что это именно журнал, альманах, периодическое издание (не монография и не отдельное издание), то вполне годится "именно разместить". "Поместить" здесь выглядело бы как пассивный процесс.